# Query TimeOut Hints not working in Eclipse Link 2.6

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Query TimeOut Hints not working in Eclipse Link 2.6 when used with MSSQL Server DB

Tried with below options.

1.Adding hints to the Query Itself
      Query query = em.createNamedQuery(AlertCategoryType.FIND_ACTIVE_TYPES);
        query.setParameter("isInactive", Boolean.FALSE);
        query.setHint(**QueryHints.JDBC_TIMEOUT**, "1");

2. Added Eclipse link hints to Named query
   @NamedQuery(name = "AlertCategoryType.findByIsInactive", query = "SELECT a              FROM AlertCategoryType a", hints={@QueryHint(name="**eclipselink.jdbc.timeout**", value="50")})
3. Added JPA hints to Named query
   @NamedQuery(name = "AlertCategoryType.findByIsInactive", query = "SELECT a              FROM AlertCategoryType a", hints={@QueryHint(name="**eclipselink.jdbc.timeout**", value="50")})
4. Tried adding property in persistence.xml

None of the above hints worked. Is there anything else missing out?
Please suggest any work around to work query time out when using any persistent provider with MSSQL server DB.

Thanks,
Vittal

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above works with MS SQL Server try with `javax.persistence.query.timeout`. Keep in mind that neither a persistence provider nor database is obliged to support it.

As specified in JPA 2.0 Specification, chapter 3.8.9. Query Hints:

> Portable applications should not rely on this hint. Depending on the
>   persistence provider and database in use, the hint may or may not be
>   observed.

---

If you are not tied to JPA 2.0 you can try with pure JDBC instead as it seems to be supported:

- [Is setQueryTimeout for JDBC driver 2.0 on CallableStatement supported?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/06bea9b9-78cb-4d1b-8c12-5f06ed991cac/is-setquerytimeout-for-jdbc-driver-20-on-callablestatement-supported?forum=sqldataaccess)
- [MSDN > JDBC Driver API Reference > setQueryTimeout Method (SQLServerStatement)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378081%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Sample JDBC Driver Applications > Connection URL Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342339%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Anchor_0)